# Defining Node Connections in .cc file rather that .ned file in Omenet++

Tags: omnet++

Is it possible to make new node connections in .cc file? I mean can I leave the connection part in .ned file empty and define connections in .cc file according to my algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Take a look at the [manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:creating-connections).
It's as easy as:

```
srcGate->connectTo(destGate);
```

or a bit more code if you need to use channels:

```
cGate *outGate, *inGate;
...

// find factory object and create a channel
cChannelType *channelType = cChannelType::get("foo.util.Channel");
cChannel *channel = channelType->create("channel");

// create connecting
outGate->connectTo(inGate, channel);
```